# Performance or other similar reasons to use foldMap instead of its variants?

Tags: haskell, fold, monoids

I have a list of some ~10.000 observations in a custom data type `observations :: [Obs]` that I want to aggregate into a statistics object `:: Stat` . A fold seemed like a sensible choice. I find myself with two options.

(1) Define a function `accumulate :: Stat -> Obs -> Stat` that I then left fold (strictly). `foldl' accumulate acc0 observations`

But my statistics object only contain accumulators such as Count and Sum, so there should be a monoidal structure. That gives me one more option

(2) define a `convert :: Obs -> Stat` and use foldMap from Data.Foldable like`foldMap convert observations`.

**my question**
What reasons are there for going the monoidal way? Performance? Maintainability? Other?

Comment: FWIW I think using foldMap makes it clearer what your intent is, and makes it harder to screw up. foldl is sufficiently flexible that you could make a mistake in your folding function, and it obscures your intent to just map-then-aggregate: other humans have to read your fold function carefully to realize it's just doing what foldMap does.

Comment: @amalloy it is an important reason. I think I'll go with that to begin with, and switch to a strict fold later if needed.